# I want to delete rows from a time series where the order is not meet a specific criteria

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Lets say I have quarterly financial data from 1990Q1 to 2000Q4. But datas are NA-s for some quarter. Lets say I have no data for 1992Q2 and 1995Q3.

In that case I want to delete all rows before 1995Q3 (including 1995Q3).

Please bear in mind, that I have many time series (as the time series are financial data of some companies).

I would greatly appreciate any help to write a code which would detect where is a missing quarter and delete all the data before them.

Rationale for the question: some financial company reports only end-of year data when it is young and later they change to quarterly reporting. When I want to calculate quarterly variables, this mess up my code, so I need to remove these periods.

I would greatly appreciate any help in advance. Kind regards, Daniel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSNKo.png)

Comment: Please share what have you done and what is the error or difficulty you are facing. It is difficult to help without those. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask better questions

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you can share the sample data. However, following code would delete all values with 'NA' from the dataset

```
dataset.replace(["NaN", 'NA', 'nan'], np.nan, inplace = True)
dataset.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
```

Comment: I uploaded a sample picture. As you can see I have end of year data for 2014 and 2015 and the quarterly data starts from 2016Q3. So in that case I want to delete the data for 2014 and 2015. But for other companies the exact date could be different than in this example.